# itertools.combinations() not displaying all combinations

Tags: python

```
print(list(combinations('decoding',4)))
```

should display all possible four letter combinations right?
But this is the output

> [('d', 'e', 'c', 'o'), ('d', 'e', 'c', 'd'), ('d', 'e', 'c', 'i'), ('d', 'e', 'c', 'n'), ('d', 'e', 'c', 'g'), ('d', 'e', 'o', 'd'), ('d', 'e', 'o', 'i'), ('d', 'e', 'o', 'n'), ('d', 'e', 'o', 'g'), ('d', 'e', 'd', 'i'), ('d', 'e', 'd', 'n'), ('d', 'e', 'd', 'g'), ('d', 'e', 'i', 'n'), ('d', 'e', 'i', 'g'), ('d', 'e', 'n', 'g'), ('d', 'c', 'o', 'd'), ('d', 'c', 'o', 'i'), ('d', 'c', 'o', 'n'), ('d', 'c', 'o', 'g'), ('d', 'c', 'd', 'i'), ('d', 'c', 'd', 'n'), ('d', 'c', 'd', 'g'), ('d', 'c', 'i', 'n'), ('d', 'c', 'i', 'g'), ('d', 'c', 'n', 'g'), ('d', 'o', 'd', 'i'), ('d', 'o', 'd', 'n'), ('d', 'o', 'd', 'g'), ('d', 'o', 'i', 'n'), ('d', 'o', 'i', 'g'), ('d', 'o', 'n', 'g'), ('d', 'd', 'i', 'n'), ('d', 'd', 'i', 'g'), ('d', 'd', 'n', 'g'), ('d', 'i', 'n', 'g'), ('e', 'c', 'o', 'd'), ('e', 'c', 'o', 'i'), ('e', 'c', 'o', 'n'), ('e', 'c', 'o', 'g'), ('e', 'c', 'd', 'i'), ('e', 'c', 'd', 'n'), ('e', 'c', 'd', 'g'), ('e', 'c', 'i', 'n'), ('e', 'c', 'i', 'g'), ('e', 'c', 'n', 'g'), ('e', 'o', 'd', 'i'), ('e', 'o', 'd', 'n'), ('e', 'o', 'd', 'g'), ('e', 'o', 'i', 'n'), ('e', 'o', 'i', 'g'), ('e', 'o', 'n', 'g'), ('e', 'd', 'i', 'n'), ('e', 'd', 'i', 'g'), ('e', 'd', 'n', 'g'), ('e', 'i', 'n', 'g'), ('c', 'o', 'd', 'i'), ('c', 'o', 'd', 'n'), ('c', 'o', 'd', 'g'), ('c', 'o', 'i', 'n'), ('c', 'o', 'i', 'g'), ('c', 'o', 'n', 'g'), ('c', 'd', 'i', 'n'), ('c', 'd', 'i', 'g'), ('c', 'd', 'n', 'g'), ('c', 'i', 'n', 'g'), ('o', 'd', 'i', 'n'), ('o', 'd', 'i', 'g'), ('o', 'd', 'n', 'g'), ('o', 'i', 'n', 'g'), ('d', 'i', 'n', 'g')]

From what i can tell
It is missing CODE.

Any idea why this is happening or is there something im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

It is present in the first item, `('d', 'e', 'c', 'o')`, as order does not matter in combinations. If you want each of those `tuple`s in each possible order, you are looking for permutations.

Answer (score 4):

This is because [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) are emitted in lexicographic sort order. Instead you need to use [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
>>> 'code' in [''.join(i) for i in permutations('decoding', 4)]
True
```